# Conditional Expectation Problem

Tags: probability

I am working on this problem and so far conditional expectation is a complete mystery to me..

$(X,Y)$ is a random variable on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with density $f(x,y)$.  If $\mathbb{E}|X|<\infty$ then 
$$\mathbb{E}(X|Y) =\frac{\int xf(x,Y)dx}{\int f(x,Y)dx}$$
Where the integrals are over the whole line.

It seems like this should somehow come from definitions easily but I have no idea why this should be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote by $f_Y$ the marginal density of $Y$, i.e.
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx,
$$
and let's assume that $f_Y(y)\neq 0$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$. Define $Z=\varphi(Y)$ where
$$
\varphi(y)=\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf(x,y)\,\mathrm dx}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx}=\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf(x,y)\,\mathrm dx}{f_Y(y)}.
$$
In order to show that $E[X\mid Y]=Z$ we have to show that

1. $Z$ is integrable.
2. $Z$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable.
3. For any $A\in\sigma(Y)$ (i.e. $A$ is of the form $A=\{Y\in B\}$ for some Borel set $B$) we have that
   $$\int_A Z\,\mathrm dP=\int_AX\,\mathrm dP.$$

Let me know if any of these causes you trouble.

Comment: Does it suffice to say that $Z$ is the quotient of measurable functions and so is measurable?

Comment: You need to show that the random variable $Z$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(Y)$. Can you see why this is obvious?

Comment: My thought was that the integrands are $\sigma(Y)$-measurable and so the integrals are, and $Z$ is then the quotient of measurable functions. Is this not correct?

Comment: Yes, another way to put it: $y\mapsto \varphi(y)$ is a Borel-measurable function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and hence the composition $Z=\varphi\circ Y$ is $\sigma(Y)$ measurable (because $Y:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable).

Comment: You're welcome.